# Configuring Debezium Connectors to Persist Across Pod/Image Restarts

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, debezium, debezium-engine, debezium-server

Imagine that we have numerous connectors to add to Debezium, and we wish to store these connectors in a configuration folder. This is to ensure that Debezium can access the connectors each time the pod or image restarts. How can I do it?